# locust - test statistics meta data

Tags: performance, csv, locust

The Locust [documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/retrieving-stats.html) does not clearly call out the various fields that will be reported in the CSV file of test statistics. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29598616/919480) that has some description of the results. Is this how test results look like? Or, are there other formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it pulls straight from the data you can manually download from the endpoint, looking like:

```
$cat foobar_distribution.csv 
"Name","# requests","50%","66%","75%","80%","90%","95%","98%","99%","100%"
"_get_token",0,"N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A"
"client _ping",2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
"client _scores",7,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5
"rpc_get_scores",7,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7
"rpc_get_token",36,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
"rpc_ping",2,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
"None Total",54,0,1,4,4,5,5,6,7,7

 $cat foobar_requests.csv 
"Method","Name","# requests","# failures","Median response time","Average response time","Min response time","Max response time","Average Content Size","Requests/s"
"Method","_get_token",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00
"Method","_ping",2,0,3,4,3,5,0,0.19
"Method","_scores",7,0,4,4,4,5,0,0.68
"Method","rpc_get_scores",7,0,5,5,4,7,0,0.68
"Method","rpc_get_token",36,0,0,0,0,1,0,3.51
"Method","rpc_ping",2,0,4,5,4,6,0,0.19
```

I apparently forgot to update the documentation for that when I made the PR... you can see the fields [here from the PR though too](https://github.com/locustio/locust/commit/0fd5c5ccde902cb88203ce4574f2829b56ccc5d0#diff-5d5f310549d6d596beaa43a1282ec49eR553).

Comment: What do the percentages mean?

Comment: Percentiles for the result times.